# acceder a un diccionario para modificar su valor en python

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un método que recibe un diccionario y quiero acceder a su valor para modificarlo con un descuento y quiero que devuelva la cesta con los valores modificados ¿alguna sugerencia?

```
def add_disccount(cesta):
    descuento = float(input("Introduce el valor del descuento: "))
    for i in range(len(cesta)):
        cesta[i].values() = (cesta[i].values()*descuento/100) - cesta[i].values()
    return cesta
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una comprensión de diccionarios:

```
descuento = float(input("Introduce el valor del descuento: "))
factor = 1 - descuento / 100
cesta = {llave: valor * factor for llave, valor in cesta.items()}
```

La comprensión de diccionarios usa `{}` para encerrar la expresión generadora. Lo primero que escribes son la llave y el valor, separados por `:`. En este caso, tenemos:

```
llave: valor * factor
```

que agrega una entrada con `llave` y valor `valor * factor`. Ambos provienen de

```
for llave, valor in cesta.items()
```

**Demo**

```
cesta = {'pan': 100, 'aceite': 200, 'azucar': 150}
descuento = float(input("Introduce el valor del descuento: "))
factor = 1 - descuento / 100
cesta = {llave: valor * factor for llave, valor in cesta.items()}
print(cesta)
```

produce:

```
Introduce el valor del descuento: 5
{'pan': 95.0, 'aceite': 190.0, 'azucar': 142.5}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Estudiaré tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

¿Quieres algo parecido a esto?

```
def add_discount(cesta):
    descuento = float(input("Introduce el valor del descuento: "))
    for p in cesta:
        p['precio'] =  p['precio'] - p['precio'] * (descuento / 100)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cesta = [dict(producto='pan', precio=0.3), dict(producto='cacao', precio=1.3), dict(producto='chuches', precio=1)]
    print(cesta)
    add_discount(cesta)
    print(cesta)
```